# Duplicate target is not shown

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

The closed-as-a-duplicate banner for *[How can I force Ruby to show a full stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380744/how-to-force-ruby-to-show-full-stack-trace)* looks like this for me:

[image: Duplicate banner]

I.e. a link to the question that it's closed as a duplicate of is not shown.

(Firefox 71.0 on 64-bit Windows)

Comment: The question was closed as a duplicate before the system tracked the master question. I've fixed this now.